# Adding ScrollSpy to multiple Divs

Tags: jquery

I have a div that un-hides according to the scroll spy parameters, but what if I want to add another div that appears under different conditions? I dont want both divs to appear at the same time, only after they are scrolled upon.

below is my JQ:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.nav').hide();
            $('#sticky-navigation').scrollspy({
                min: $('.nav').offset().top,
                onEnter: function(element, position) {
                    $(".nav").show('hide');
                },

            });
        });
</script>
```

Thanks! JOE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joe,

It's hard to know exactly what your trying to do from your just the snippet in your posting, but I think you should look at the colors example from the plugin site: https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy/blob/master/examples/colors.html

This is the main code snippet that executes the Javascript"

```
$('.color').each(function(i) {
    var position = $(this).position();
    console.log(position);
    console.log('min: ' + position.top + ' / max: ' + parseInt(position.top + $(this).height()));
    $(this).scrollspy({
        min: position.top,
        max: position.top + $(this).height(),
        onEnter: function(element, position) {
            if (console) console.log('entering ' + element.id);
            $("body").css('background-color', element.id);
        },
        onLeave: function(element, position) {
            if (console) console.log('leaving ' + element.id);
            //    $('body').css('background-color','#eee');
        }
    });
});
```

He Gives each of the divs he is trying to fire a class of "color" and then uses a loop to assign a function to each specific div. In this example he is assigning background-color, but you could just as easily show or hide the divs themselves. If you can't stuff the behavior into a loop, you can always assign the scrollspy functions individually for each div.

Paul

Comment: Thanks Paul,

I was able to set it up so that instead of switching the CSS Background color, it fadesIn on a div that was set as hidden. 

However I cannot figure out how to do this as a loop, only individually. The details are in the question below...

Thanks!